# $(x^2)^\frac{3}{2}=x^3$ or $|x|^3$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$(x^2)^\frac{3}{2}=x^{2*\frac{3}{2}}=x^3$

$(x^2)^\frac{3}{2}=(x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}*3}=(\sqrt{x^2})^3=|x|^3$

What's the correct way?

Comment: Note how the parentheses are arranged.  *First* square $x$, and then...

Comment: The way it was written, the square is inside of the parentheses and should be evaluated first.  Be warned that $(a^b)^c$ is *not* simply going to equal $a^{(bc)}$ like you may be thinking you were taught.  That is only going to be true in certain restrictive situations such as when $b$ and $c$ are both integers, or when $a$ is a positive real number.

Comment: If $x$ is negative, then $(x^2)^{3\over 2}$ is positive and $x^3$ is negative.

Comment: Be warned also that people may come behind and try to claim that exponentiation is multivalued.  In certain contexts it may be okay to do that... however in the most standard of contexts we very specifically require exponentiation to give a single result.

Comment: Compare this with $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$, and you will see that the second way is correct.

Comment: $f(\pm a) = \left((\pm a)^2\right)^{\frac 32} = (a^2)^{\frac32} = |a|^3 = |a^3|$

Good question. Please know that this is self-explanatory. Also, please question yourself, think, and rethink before deciding to seek help from others. That is the only way to see beauty and enjoy the adventure.

Comment: Note $(x^2)^{3/2}=|x|^3$ for real $x$ (but not complex $x$).  However, $(x^{3/2})^2$ is undefined when $x<0$ (unless we go to the complex numbers).

Comment: The parentheses are there for a reason, yet you ignore them. Notice $(x^2) > 0$ always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will define a function $f(x)=(x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}$.
For $x>0$, $f(x)=(x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}=x^3=|x|^3$.
On the other hand for $x<0$. We have $f(x)=(x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}$. Because of $x^2$ we can see that $f(x)>0$, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ and as such $\forall x<0$. Meaning that $f(x)$ can't be negative which means $f(x)\ne x^3$ (at least for $x<0$), so it is $f(x)=|x|^3$.